# float div in between 2 left/ right aligned divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a div floated left, and a div floated right with a variable gap in between the 2 (responsive).

I need to be able to fill the gap in the middle with a colour, but only the gap in the middle (it can not flow behind the other 2 divs, as these divs have transparent backgrounds)

how can I achieve this with html structure like:

**html**

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav">
    </ul>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <ul class="nav right">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.nav-wrap{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.nav{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav.right{
    float:right;
}

.filler{
    ?????
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use table layout of this purpose.

```
.nav-wrap{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.nav{
    display:table-cell;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


.filler{
     display:table-cell;
     background: ?;
     height:50px;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/T7vXr/2/)

Comment: Also a nice solution. A side effect is that the 'filler' and the navs will have the same height.

Comment: I would also add `table-layout:fixed;` to nav-wrap otherwise it will allow the side columns to reduce in size when the screen shrinks

Comment: didnt think of this! but unfortunately we have to support down to IE7 :(

Answer (score 2):

For filler, give it a margin that is equal to the width of the navs:

```
.filler{
    margin: 0 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

To make this work, put both navs before the div in the HTML:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav">
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav right">
    </ul>
    <div class="filler">X</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yyZz6/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following html:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav left">
    </ul>
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <ul class="nav right">
    </ul>
</div>
```

With the following styles:

```
.nav-wrap{
    padding:0 200px;
    overflow:auto;
}

.nav{
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav.right{
    float:right;
    margin-right:-200px;
}

.nav.left{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-200px;
}

.filler{
    width:100%; float:left;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4paUf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `flex-grow` of CSS [flexbox](http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2014/05/css-flexbox-explained-with-examples.html)

```
.filler{
    background: SaddleBrown; flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2nN6k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve responsive design you should not use fixed width. Instead i suggest you try this:

```
   <div class="nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav">

    </ul>
    <div class="filler">

    </div>
    <ul class="nav">

    </ul>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.nav-wrap{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.nav, .filler{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.nav{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:13%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


.filler{
    float: left;
    width: 64%;
}
<style>
```